# File-local variables not parsed in lilypond file

Tags: file-local-variables, lilypond

I have a `definitions.ly` file that ends with the following:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% LilyPond-master-file: "score.ly"
%%% End:
```

However, the value of `LilyPond-master-file` is still `nil` when I visit the file.

If I do `M-: RET (inibit-local-variables-p) RET` I get `nil`.

If I save the exact same file with a different extension (eg. `.foo`), emacs asks me (upon loading) if I want to set the unsafe variable, as expected.

I've tried using a directory-local variable, but it doesn't work either.

I've tried setting another variable, like `fill-column`, using the snippet above, in the same file, without success.

Maybe there's something in lilypond-mode preventing the parsing of local variables?

I'm out of ideas and I don't know how to debug this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this and it's probably a bug, but `lilypond-mode.el` (at least my version of it) is very old and has not seen much updating. Not even sure where to report the bug.

As a workaround however, you can do it in the mode hook:

```el
(defun ndk/lilypond-mode-prep ()
   (hack-local-variables)
   ;; maybe other stuff
   )

(add-to-hook 'LilyPond-mode-hook #'ndk/lilypond-mode-prep)
```